# requestAnimationFrame() performance issue

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I experienced performance issues with requestAnimationFrame().

Consider the following code. It's a simple loop which prints the time since the last frame every time this time delta is larger than 20ms.

```
const glob_time_info = {delta_time: 0.0, last_frame: performance.now()};

var render = function (timestamp) {
    glob_time_info.delta_time = timestamp - glob_time_info.last_frame;
    glob_time_info.last_frame = timestamp; 
    if(glob_time_info.delta_time > 20)
        console.log(glob_time_info.delta_time);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
};
render(performance.now());
```

As I understood requestAnimationFrame this snippet should never print anything, because it tries to run 60 times a second (60Hz as my monitor). 
Therefore time delta should always be somewhat around 16-17ms.

But it prints times around 33ms every few seconds.
Why?

I experienced this on windows 10 with Chrome 54 and Firefox 49. I own an i5-6600

---

**UPDATE**
Here the output of Nit's script for windows and ubuntu. Windows, what are you doing?
Windows 10 (PC):
[image]
WIndows 8 (same netbook as below):
[image]
Ubuntu (same netbook as above):
[image]

Comment: It is pegged at 16 and change when I run it.  Probably related to garbage collection and other stuff your computer is doing.

Comment: "tries" being the keyword, if something is blocking the thread, even for a few milliseconds, it no longer succeeds

Comment: I also thought about the GC, but every few seconds? and what does he have to collect :) And how can you make smooth animations if every few seconds the framerate drops down to 30FPS or worse

Comment: `And how can you make smooth animations if every few seconds the framerate drops down to 30FPS or worse` - by making the animations time based rather than frame based

Comment: Of course I did it frame independent. but you can clearly see the jump the objects do if there was a large time delta

Comment: I mean one (I) can clearly see the difference between 60fps and 20-30fps in my animation. But I assume I'm doing something wrong, because I never noticed these jumps in other webgl-animations.

Comment: This is more than likely related to the way the Operating System is running the CPU than anything to do with your code.

Comment: you are right, I just tested it on ubuntu, and time delta is 16.6*ms all the time! But something such basic should also work on windows. But I think there is nothing I can do. Thank you!
Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to test your hypothesis that the issue is related to the platform you're running on - measure the performance.

Shortly put, run `requestAnimationFrame` a number of times similar to how you did and note down a timestamp on each run. After that simply visualize the results.

```js
var times = [];
var measure = function() {
  times.push(new Date().getTime());
  if (times.length > 100) return draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(measure);
};
var draw = function() {
  var dataset = {
    x: [],
    y: [],
    type: 'bar'
  };
  var layout = {
    xaxis: {
      title: 'measurement #'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'iteration duration (ms)'
    },
    height: 250
  };
  var options = {
    displayModeBar: false
  };
  times.reduce(function(previous, current, i) {
    dataset.x.push(i);
    dataset.y.push(current - previous);
    return current;
  }, times.shift());
  Plotly.newPlot('target', [dataset], layout, options);
}
measure();
```

```css
#target {
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

You can run the same simulation on different operating systems and different browsers to see if you can narrow down the issue further.

Comment: Thanks! I put the pictures in the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Travis J stated in the comments it's related to the operating system.

This performance issue doesn't appear on linux. So there is nothing I (we) can do about it.

Comment: "it's related to the operating system" --- well, a windows 10 and a less powerful cpu here: I get 15-16ms per iteration.

Comment: I also get 15-16ms, but every few seconds peaks do appear. Have you tried my code snippet?

Comment: Nope, I run the one from the other answer.

Comment: I added diagrams to the question

Comment: Increased their script to run 1000 times and got a perfectly stable graph: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eddmfiymzbcwdrz/Screenshot%202016-11-11%2012.58.49.png?dl=0

Comment: yes looks pretty good! Weird. we need a userstudy, more data! :)